# return filename of uploaded file with multer and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, multer

I am creating a simple application as a learning experience with ionic 2 that connects to a node server running multer to upload images. The problem I am running into is, I need to get the final file name from multer back to the app that uploaded it, to save it locally. I am using the Auth and User modules from @ionic/cloud-angular for authentication and user information. The User object has a details object with things like "name", "email", "username", "image", ...
So, when an image is uploaded to the node server and multer saves it, I need to get that filename back to the application so I can update the user.details.image property.

Here is a simple version of my node server...

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var cors = require('cors');
var postStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        let fileName = '', postName;
        if(typeof req.body.postName !== "undefined") {
            postName = req.body.postName.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
            filename += postName;
        }
        fileName += new Date().getTime();
        fileName += ".png";
        callback(null, fileName);
    }
});
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors());
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var uploadPost = multer({storage: postStorage}).single('post_image');
    uploadPost(req, res, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("error uploading file");
        }
        res.end("file uploaded");
    });
});
app.listen(app.get('port');
console.log("app listening on port: " _ app.get('port'));
```

Is there a way to have it send back the final file name that multer saved?  Something like res.json({fileName: fileName}); res.end();
I really don't know at this point, and all the tutorials I can find on multer just show how to create a new filename and save a file in disk or database or memory, but nowhere does it show how you can actually get that filename back to the application that uploaded it.
Thank you in advance for any help, I really appreciate it. If you need to see the ionic 2 code that uploads the stuff please let me know and I will update the post with that code as well. Thank you.

Comment: Is this how you code IRL? No line breaks between lines? Ouch...

Comment: No, I was trying to condense the code and simplify it for posting. I'm sure people would get a little annoyed if I posted up 200 lines of code, that could be done in 50. I figured that would be better for the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are uploading single file you can get filename using `req.file.filename`

if you upload multiple files `req.files`

Once you got file name , you can send it to client using  `res.send({filename:FileName});`

Comment: that part isn't the problem, I have been able to upload the file no problem, but I can't figure out how to return the new file name to the uploading application. since I am creating a new filename with multer, I need to tell the application that uploaded the file, what the new filename is.

Comment: As an example, lets say I use ajax...
$.ajax({
    url: "localhost:3000/upload",
    data: {post_image: [FILENAME]},
    success: function(msg) {
        //need the new filename here
    }
});

Comment: res.send({filename:name_of_your_file}); is this you want?

Comment: Looks like that worked perfectly, thank you @Dinesh
One last question on here, why would req.body be {} and have nothing in it when I am sending a file, and postName=test

Comment: Because you are not sending any form fields. If you send form fields it will be in req.body. If you send file it will be in req.file. I updated my answer pls accept it if helped. Thanks